# parse JSON and malipulate its object values

Tags: shell-script, json, jq

I have a json file named xyz.json as follows

```
[
    {
        "annotations": [ "a" , "b" , "c" ],
        "class": "image",
        "filename": "vc00_02201.png"
    },
    {
        "annotations": [],
        "class": "image",
        "filename": "vc00_02202.png"
    }
    {
        "annotations": [],
        "class": "image",
        "filename": "vc00_02203.png"
    },
    {
        "annotations": [],
        "class": "image",
        "filename": "vc00_02204.png"
    }
]
```

I need to copy the object "annotations" from "filename": "vc00_02201.png"
to "annotations" of "filename": "vc00_02204.png" within the same xyz.json file using a shell script.
Expected output:

```
[
    {
        "annotations": [ "a" , "b" , "c" ],
        "class": "image",
        "filename": "vc00_02201.png"
    },
    {
        "annotations": [],
        "class": "image",
        "filename": "vc00_02202.png"
    }
    {
        "annotations": [],
        "class": "image",
        "filename": "vc00_02203.png"
    },
    {
        "annotations": [ "a" , "b" , "c" ],
        "class": "image",
        "filename": "vc00_02204.png"
    }
]
```

Comment: Does it have to be shell script? This would certainly be easier in a scripting language with JSON support (all of the major ones, including at least Perl, Python, and Ruby). Also, if it has to be shell, which external utilities can you use? Can you use something like [`jq`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) ?

Comment: yes I can use jq and python script is also fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
$cat xyz.json | jq '.[3].annotations=.[0].annotations'
```

Comment: +1, You can do `jq ... xyz.json` as well instead of using `cat`.

Comment: it says  xyz.json : command not found

Comment: don't copy the "$" sign before ``cat``

Comment: It says the same with out copy of $ sign

Answer (score 0):

this is also achievable via *[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc)* in one line:

```
bash $ cat xyz.json | jtc -w'<vc00_02204.png>[-1][annotations]' -eu jtc -w'<vc00_02201.png>[-1][annotations]' xyz.json \; 
[
   {
      "annotations": [
         "a",
         "b",
         "c"
      ],
      "class": "image",
      "filename": "vc00_02201.png"
   },
   {
      "annotations": [],
      "class": "image",
      "filename": "vc00_02202.png"
   },
   {
      "annotations": [],
      "class": "image",
      "filename": "vc00_02203.png"
   },
   {
      "annotations": [
         "a",
         "b",
         "c"
      ],
      "class": "image",
      "filename": "vc00_02204.png"
   }
]
bash $
```

Of course, it could have been done via referencing direct members of array, like:

```
bash $ cat xyz.json | jtc -w'[3][annotations]' -eu jtc -w'[0][annotations]' xyz.json \;
```

but then whole point of cross-referencing by filename would be moot.